# What happens when contract is making delegatecall to deleted contract?

Tags: solidity, parity, delegatecall

I read the whole Suicide Parity Multi-sig hack. One thing I don't understand is what happens when you call delegate call on deleted contract?
I thought that contract should throw an exception but due to the attack description it doesn't. Why this code returned true?

```
function isOwner(address _addr) constant returns (bool) {
   return _walletLibrary.delegatecall(msg.data);
}
```

Comment: The zeroed out functions return false. However delegatecall does not handle return values. [See this related question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8099/delegatecall-and-function-return-values)

Comment: Ok, so what was the point to have that method on the `Wallet` level? Since it wasn't returning `delegagecall` result? What it was used for? Or was that just some leftover?

Comment: Ok, it looks like another bug in Parity https://github.com/paritytech/parity/issues/6201