# delegatecall return wrong value

Tags: solidity, blockchain, smart-contract-wallets, delegatecall

I want to get userInfo which is masterchef's methods.

But I want to call userInfo from another contract, so I'm using `delegatecall`

```
address sender = msg.sender;
(bool success, bytes memory result) = contractAddr.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("userInfo(uint256,address)", _pid, sender));
```

I have the following results:

```
"success": true,
"result": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

and from master chef [image: master chef image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [delegatecall and function return values](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8099/delegatecall-and-function-return-values)

Comment: Hi GabrielElfassi! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! Why are you using `delegatecall` instead of `call`?